# No ContextMenuChanging(ed) event in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, wpf-controls, adorner

I have a custom Shape - `MyShape` - (may be control, does not matter).

`MyShape` has an adorner - `TextAdorner`.

The `TextAdorner` should have the same ContextMenu as `MyShape` (because they represents the same unique object).

The CustomMenu of MyShape is changed in the code in some conditions. 
So, I need to detect the moment when `MyShape` changes its CustomMenu to update the adorner ContextMenu too.

However, there is no `ContextMenuChanging`, nor `ContextMenuChanged` events.

I use this code for first ContemxtMenu assignment, however when the adorned element changes the context menu, I don't know how to synchronize them.

```
public class TextAdorner : Adorner
{
    public TextAdorner(UIElement adornedElement)
        : base(adornedElement)
    {
        this.ContextMenu = (adornedElement as MyShape).ContextMenu;
    }
```

How should I proceed in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is to create a one-way binding on the `ContextMenu` property from your `MyShape` object to your `TextAdorner`

so :

```
public class TextAdorner : Adorner
{
    public TextAdorner(UIElement adornedElement)
        : base(adornedElement)
    {
        Binding myBinding = new Binding("ContextMenu");
        myBinding.Source = (adornedElement as MyShape);
        this.SetBinding(FrameworkElement.ContextMenuProperty,myBinding);
    }
}
```

reference : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742863.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Instead of just assigning the ContextMenu property, create a Binding.  That way, the framework will handle updates for you.  You can create a binding with the adornedElement parameter as a source like this:

```
public class TextAdorner : Adorner
{
    public TextAdorner(UIElement adornedElement)
        : base(adornedElement)
    {
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(
            this,
            FrameworkElement.ContextMenuProperty,
            new Binding
            {
                Path = new PropertyPath(FrameworkElement.ContextMenuProperty),
                Source = adornedElement
            });
    }
```

You could also bind using the AdornedElement property on the Adorner:

```
BindingOperations.SetBinding(
    this,
    FrameworkElement.ContextMenuProperty,
    new Binding("AdornedElement.ContextMenu")
    {
        RelativeSource = RelativeSource.Self
    });
```

This approach will work if you need to specify the binding in XAML:

```
<Something ContextMenu="{Binding AdornedElement.ContextMenu, 
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
```

Comment: thanks. Does your code does the same thing like the proposed by Johan Buret?

Comment: @serhio: Yes, they should do exactly the same thing.